# How to tell when OSMF player has finished Playing the video

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5, osmf

I have built a OSMF player info my mobile flex application but I can't find a way to tell when the video is done playing. Can I somehow tell when the video is completed? 
Thanks in advance!

```
        import mx.core.UIComponent;

        import org.osmf.events.TimeEvent;

        import spark.components.Button;
        import spark.components.Group;


        public var playerInstance:StrobeMediaPlayback;
        public var grp:Group = new Group();
        protected function init(event:Event):void
        {

            _stage = systemManager.stage;
            _stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            _parameters  =
                {
                    src:"assets/Mini film 2b with filter on.mp4"
                    , controlBarMode:"docked"
                    , controlBarAutoHide: true
                    , autoPlay: true
                    , playButtonOverlay:true
                    , showVideoInfoOverlayOnStartUp: true
                };

            var playerInstance:StrobeMediaPlayback = new StrobeMediaPlayback();
            playerInstance.initialize(_parameters, _stage, systemManager.loaderInfo, null);
            playerInstance = playerInstance;
            //playerInstance.addEventListener(, remove);
            var ui:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
            ui.addChild(playerInstance as DisplayObject);

            grp.percentWidth = 100;
            grp.percentHeight = 100;
            addElement(grp);
            grp.addElement(ui);
            actionBarVisible = false

        }

        private var urlLoader:URLLoader;
        private var urlRequest:URLRequest;
        private var loader:Loader;
        private var _stage:Stage;
        private var _parameters:Object;
        /* static */
        private static const ALLOW_LOAD_BYTES_CODE_EXECUTION:String = "allowLoadBytesCodeExecution";


        public function emptyCache():void
        {
            //playerInstance.player.pause();

            grp.removeAllElements();
            this.destructionPolicy = "auto";
        }
```

Comment: I actually am running into a similar issue. I am going to try a few things and I will post the result here after the fact.

Comment: Thank you if i find something i will let you know.

Comment: I actually ended up having total success with using the TimeEvent.COMPLETE. It is working for streaming, psuedo streaming and basic progressive download (i am playing .mp4 and .f4f depending on the playback method). That said, you might want to edit the MediaPlayer.currentTimeUpdateInterval.

Comment: Are your events not firing at the end of the video or is it firing prematurely?

Comment: There aren't firing at all. It would get to the end and just sit there.

Comment: Have you tried adding the CURRENT_TIME_CHANGE event to see if that fires? If it does you should be able to check if( event.curentTime > player.duration ) { /* end video*/ }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
player.addEventListener(TimeEvent.COMPLETE, onComplete);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onComplete() {
  console.log("Completed");
}
```

`player.addEventListener("complete", onComplete);`

API doc
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/org/osmf/events/TimeEvent.html